# "Read timed out" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cloudbees

I'm getting this error in eclipse when trying to make new CloudBees project:

> Failed to complete ClickStart project provisioning: Read timed out

Does anyone know why this error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

This could be that the clickstart is taking too long to complete - the timeout is set pretty high - of the order of minutes.

Can you run the clickstart from the web interface and see if it works there (or try a different one?)

Any information from the eclipse log would help people diagnose too.